# How to render nested routes in multiple outlets (react router v6.8)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I build a react app with react router 6.8.
For my app I have the following structure:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />} errorElement={<Error />}>
        <Route path="motive">
          <Route
            path=":motiveSlug"
            element={
              <MotiveSingle />
            }>
            <Route path="artist">
              <Route
                path=":artistSlug"
                element={
                  <ArtistSingle />
                }
              />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    )
  );
```

This is how I would like to render the Outlets of the elements in :

```
<div id="configurator">
 {/* Outlet MotiveSingle */}
</div>
<div id="content">
 {/* Outlet ArtistSingle */}
</div>
```

I want to render the `MotiveSingle` in `#configurator`. The Motive details contain the Artist. On click of the Artist Link I want to render the `ArtistSingle` in `#content`.

How can I achieve, that `MotiveSingle` gets rendered in `#configurator` and `ArtistSingle` in `#content`?

Here is a live demo you can inspect:
https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-outlets-in-nested-routes-ckumkk

Here is the Layout for better understanding:
[image]

Comment: Are you saying you want motives rendered into one outlet while artists are rendered into another outlet? Or are you saying that you want the `ArtistSingle` to be rendered inside `MotiveSingle`? Can you [edit] to clarify better what you are trying to do, where exactly you want content rendered? See also [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for not make it clear enough. I wanted to show the whole case for better understanding. I want that the `ArtistSingle` is rendered outside of the `MotiveSingle`. `MotiveSingle` should rendered in configurator and `ArtistSingle` should render in content.

Comment: And do you want these `MotiveSingle` and `ArtistSingle` components to be matched and rendered simultaneously, or independent, of one another? I don't see where a second outlet is necessary, but it's still not clear where and how you want these components to be rendered. Like I said, perhaps a better and more complete [mcve] would help us see better what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Independent. In `MotiveSingle` I provide the link to the Artist. When I click the Artist link, I want to display the `ArtistSingle` in Outlet "content" and not in Outlet 
 "configurator" where `MotiveSingle` get rendered.

Comment: Are these two "outlets" supposed to be two separate parts of the UI? This is the part that isn't making any sense yet. So far you've only shown us the routes, but none of the UI.

Comment: There are two outlets because I still want to show the `MotiveSingle` when `ArtistSingle` is active. I will try to edit my post to clarify it.

Comment: Right, and that should be the default behavior if `MotiveSingle` is rendering an `Outlet` for ***its*** nested children routes. Do you you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that we could inspect live?

Comment: I added a live demo and simplified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the routes a bit and achieve what I think you describe with just an additional Motive layout route. The main issue is that each `Route` component only has one `children` prop/sets of nested routes, and so they can only be rendered into a single `Outlet` component. This is fixed my just rendering `MotiveSingle` directly in a layout route instead of the additional `Outlet`.

Example:

```
function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="motive/motive-1">Motive 1</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="motive/motive-2">Motive 2</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="motive/motive-3">Motive 3</NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <hr />

      <main>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const MotiveLayout = () => (
  <>
    <div id="configurator">
      <i>Configurator</i>
      <MotiveSingle />
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="content">
      <i>Content</i>
      {/* Outlet for ArtistSingle */}
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  </>
);
```

```
export default function App() {
  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />} errorElement={<Error />}>
        <Route path="motive/:motiveSlug" element={<MotiveLayout />}>
          <Route path="artist/:artistSlug" element={<ArtistSingle />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    )
  );
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-render-nested-routes-in-multiple-outlets-react-router-v6-8]

[image]

Comment: Nice!! Thanks for your answer! The thing is in `#content` I have a lot of other stuff. Wouldn't it a problem when I load the same stuff all the time again, just when I want to see another motive?

Comment: @ferdinand What sorts of "stuff" is loaded in the artists/content section? I guess it depends on what specifically you need to render/load when the artist sub-routes change.

Comment: I added a picture for better understanding. The "stuff" is basically the whole website content. This should be replaced when clicking on the Artist link.

Comment: @ferdinand I don't see any issue if clicking around in the left panel means different content needs to be rendered in the right panel. In the images you just added it seems you are basically adding a "sidebar" that controls a "main content" area.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I guess I have it now. I added `<Route index element={<Content />} />` as a child of `motive/:motiveSlug ` path. So I render always the Content, when the`<ArtistSingle />` is not rendered.